# Is there another solution for SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a small problem :

```
SELECT *
FROM  ZGA_DASHBOARD_FINAL
full outer join A_SGA_Name_ID_Final ON cast(REFERENCE_KEY1 as integer) =A_SGA_Name_ID_Final.[PERSONID_EXT]
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REFERENCE_KEY1) = 1
```

For my output I have this error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CORRECT' to data type int.

and when I change full outer join by Inner join it works 
Someone had the same problem..
Thanks in advance

Comment: See [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if that does not work.. I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody wants to ask, and even if it worked, SQL Server offers no guarantee over evaluation order. (And if it did guarantee to match the *logical* processing order, say, `FROM/JOIN/ON` are logically processed before `WHERE`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to first limit the records where the ISNUMERIC returns true:

```
; WITH NumericReference
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  ZGA_DASHBOARD_FINAL
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(REFERENCE_KEY1) = 1
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM  [NumericReference] nr
    FULL OUTER JOIN A_SGA_Name_ID_Final af 
        ON CAST(nr.REFERENCE_KEY1 AS INTEGER) = af.[PERSONID_EXT]
```

Comment: Again, a) `ISNUMERIC` answers a question nobody wants to ask, and b) The *whole* query is optimized and SQL Server doesn't guarantee evaluation order. (`ISNUMERIC` returns true for `$0,,,,,,,0`, as an example, which isn't convertible to `int`)

Comment: Then propose a better solution.

Comment: The solution is for them to use columns with the correct data types and not be attempting conversion during querying. However, most people asking questions here are *reluctant* to hear that and unable or unwilling to change. There are no good solutions if that's the case.

Comment: I agree, but there's a way to make that a compelling argument, with examples, in an answer, in stead of as a snide comment. Be helpful.

Comment: @RussellFox I don't think that Damien's comment was snide at all. He is pointing out that the fundamental problem here is not the query but the design decision to use the wrong datatype. Your query will work in most situations but it is not addressing the real issue with the OPs database.

Comment: The problems of ISNUMERIC aside, this might be better to use TRY_CAST so that it won't crash on invalid "integers".

Comment: I apologise if you were offended by my comments. But my point was that CTEs don't change the *actual evaluation order* of predicates within the engine. (This was, admittedly, point b). The engine may still choose to evaluate the `CAST` or `CONVERT` before any `WHERE` clause condition. We've been asking Microsoft to fix this for over a decade but no traction yet. It's likely that your answer will yield an identical execution plan as the original query